# Change screen brightness onPause (Android app)

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

My app saves the user original brightness with:

`originalBrightness = Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS;`

and then changes it while the program running.

originalBrightness is private global string. Now what I am trying to do is when the user clicks on "Home" or when the app paused the original screen is need to be set again, I have tried to do this like this but the app crushes:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    int brightness = Integer.getInteger(originalBrightness);
    setBrightness(brightness);
}
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = brightness / 100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

Is there away to male it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using `Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS` to set system default brightness as:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),  
android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,brightness /100.0f); // 0-255
```

and add these permission's in manifest  :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: can you explain what dose android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),  
android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,brightness /100.0f); // 0-255

Comment: @VladIoffe :currently you are setting brightness for Activity not for device default brightness as you mention in question `when the user clicks on "Home" or when the app paused the original screen is need to be set again ` means you want to restore device default brightness then this is done automatically from device.if you have any issue then you will need to modify system default settings as my answer